# Necesito ayuda para mostrar esta matriz en c#

Tags: c#, matrices

hola que tal soy nuevo en c# y me mandaron a hacer esta matriz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora bien ya hice todo pero no me queda todo en el mismo orden sino que me sale el igual y el resultado en diferentes lineas abajo. Ya intente muchas formas, en todas las que intente, o me da todo un mismo valor como resultado o todo numero 0 como resultado.

por el momento este es mi codigo

```
int[,] mat = new int[5, 5] {{0,1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4,5},{2,3,4,5,6},{3,4,5,6,7},{4,5,6,7,8}};

            for (int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
                {
                    Console.Write(mat[fil,col] + " ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            int fsum = 0;
            for (int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
            {
                fsum = 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
                {
                    fsum = fsum + mat[fil, col];
                }
                Console.Write("= " + fsum);
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
```

obviamente entiendo el porque al resultado me lo genera abajo, pero es la unica manera que pude lograr que me de el resultado correcto. Ahora me queda unirlos pero no me sale como, llevo 1 semana con lo mismo

Muchas gracias, sus saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A ver..mira tu codigo.. donde es que apretas enter y vas a la siguiente linea? te sobra un enter en algun lado.. cuando imprimis en consola, no vas y volves.. imprimis en una linea, y luego vas a la otra.. tenes que imprimir toda la linea al mismo tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Es muy fácil, solo tienes que validar cuando alcanzas el ultimo dato de cada fila y luego añadir la suma de todas las columnas pertenecientes a cada fila.

Así

```
int[,] mat = new int[5, 5] { { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 } };

            for (int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
                {
                    sum += mat[fil, col];

                    if (col == 4)
                    {
                        Console.Write(mat[fil, col] + " = " + sum);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(mat[fil, col] + " ");
                    }

                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que usas dos bucles con anidación cuando en realidad sólo precisas de uno:

```
int[,] mat = new int[5, 5] {{0,1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4,5},{2,3,4,5,6},{3,4,5,6,7},{4,5,6,7,8}};

for (int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
{
    int fsum = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
        Console.Write(mat[fil, col] + " ");
        fsum = fsum + mat[fil, col];  // va calculando la suma de la línea
    }
    Console.Write("= " + fsum);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema que tiene tu código es muy sencillo de solucionar, normalmente le empezamos a dar vueltas a algo cuya solución es tan simple como borrar uno de los bucles.

```
int[,] mat = new int[5, 5] { { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 } };

        for (int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
        {
            byte fsum = 0;
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(mat[fil, col] + " ");
                fsum = (byte)(fsum + mat[fil, col]);
            }
            Console.Write("= " + fsum);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Destacar que he cambiado el int fsum por byte para ahorrar espacio en la memoria, por eso luego en el bucle anidado, he realizado una conversión explícita. Pero no es necesario. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Te respondo con otra variante a las respuestas anteriores, que me parece más simple y que además con algunos cambios podría hacer otra matriz. Te dejo el código a continuación.

```
for (int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
{
    int fsum = 0;
    for (int col = fil; col < fil+5; col++)
    {
        Console.Write(col + " ");
        fsum = fsum + col;  // va calculando la suma de la línea
    }
    Console.Write("= " + fsum);
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```